# How pip knows what path to include when compiles?

Tags: windows, pip, mysql-python

I am trying to install MySQL-python with pip for 64-bit python. For this I want to use `MySQL Connector C 6.0.2` which installed under `c:\Program Files\MySQL\`, but pip tries find it in `-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include` :

```
C:\Users\navis\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe 
/c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" 
-IC:\Python27_64\include -Id:\projects\jop\venv_jop_print_py2_64\PC /Tc_mysql.c 
/Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
```

How to point it to right include path which I have?

PS: prehistory - sometimes ago I used 32-bit python with 32-bit mysql-connector so this situations looks for me like I need to purge something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with manual pointing to include path and library path:

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext 
--global-option="-IC:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" 
--global-option="-LC:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt"  mysql-python==1.2.5
```

But it is still interesting why pip wants another version.

Answer (score 0):

for windows and multiple include/lib directories use '**;**' separator (semicolon) other OS might use ':' (colon)

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext 
--global-option="-IC:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include;C:\otherDir;C:\otherDir2" 
--global-option="-LC:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt;C:\otherDir3"  mysql-python==1.2.5
```